# Oracle, Merge statement not working

Tags: sql, oracle10g

My intention is to avoid attempting to insert the same record into a database.
This statement does not insert the record. The record referenced in the select does not already exist so it should insert. Any ideas where I am going wrong.

```
MERGE INTO XX0101.CAMPAIGN b
    USING (SELECT * FROM  XX0101.CAMPAIGN WHERE CAMPAIGN_ID=7 AND X_ID='0123' AND Y_ID='4567') a
    ON (a.CAMPAIGN_ID = b.CAMPAIGN_ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CAMPAIGN_ID, X_ID, Y_ID, ROW_LAST_UPDATE_TS, ROW_LAST_UPDATE_ID)
    VALUES (7, '0123', '4567', SYSDATE, 'ABC');
```

Comment: Uh .. you're querying a record from a table, and then asking Oracle to find it in the same table (which of course it finds it) .. so since it was matched, it doesn't INSERT .. why would you think it would insert it ?

Comment: My understanding of MERGE is that the select is performed first on the table and if the record does not exist then it will proceed with the insert. I However I may be mistaken as I just came across the feature and may have misunderstood the feature.

Comment: You are "sort of" correct.  First Oracle retrieves all the rows in the `USING` clause. It then joins that result set "a" .. to your initial table "b" ... using the `ON` clause to join.  If that matches or not, is what you are checking. Since your result set in "a" is empty (since `CAMPAIGN_ID=7` doesn't exist), there is nothing to MERGE .. ;)   I assume you have a Primary key or unique constraint ? If so, why not just `INSERT` and let Oracle tell you it exists via `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a job for `MERGE`, but rather for a simple `INSERT`.

```
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO XX0101.CAMPAIGN 
          (CAMPAIGN_ID, X_ID, Y_ID, ROW_LAST_UPDATE_TS, ROW_LAST_UPDATE_ID)
         VALUES (7, '0123', '4567', SYSDATE, 'ABC');
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        NULL;
  END;
  /
```

this assumes you have a PK or unique index in there.

Comment: I have a PK so I will use this  approach.